# Magento 2 foreign key error saving configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, foreign-key

I created a Magento 2.0.2 store and used :

https://github.com/ubertheme/magento2_data_migration/releases

to import from my 1.9.2 store.  When i try to save one of my configurable products I get this error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gaxle_magento2`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) O), query was: UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `attribute_set_id` = ?, `type_id` = ?, `sku` = ?, `has_options` = ?, `required_options` = ?, `created_at` = '2013-02-07 06:18:07', `updated_at` = '2015-11-30 20:57:16' WHERE (`entity_id`=44)
```

I don't get this error saving all configurable products. Just this one from what i can tell.  Any ideas?

Comment: A side note.  I'm not leaving out info in the query.  The ?s are literal.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that this configurable product is assigned to attribute set that not exists in system. Try assign it to "default" set and problem should be fixed.

Comment: My default attribute set id is 4.  This query :

`select attribute_set_id, type_id, sku, has_options, required_options, created_at, updated_at
from catalog_product_entity
WHERE entity_id IN (44)`

shows that the id is right. See result:

`attribute_set_id  type_id  sku  has_options required_options created_at updated_at  
4  configurable  GA-SWLSCorona  1  1  2013-02-07 00:18:07  2015-11-30 14:57:16`

Comment: also, this query returns no results.  <br/> 
`SELECT *
FROM catalog_product_entity
WHERE attribute_set_id NOT
IN (

SELECT attribute_set_id
FROM eav_attribute_set
);`

Comment: Have you got it solved ? I'm getting the fk error when I try to enable the product. If I edit other values and save, it works. Values in both tables seem correct.